# Windows 10 PC Did not Start Properly Loop

Tags: windows-10

How do I get past the Windows 10 automatic repair loop without losing my files?  I created a USB reboot for Windows 10.  But when I have tried to use that, the computer asks me to remove the disk and allow windows to "start normally."  Its direction then notes that I can then insert the installation media and restart the "upgrade."  It is not an upgrade.  And windows is not starting normally --that is why I need to go through this.  Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: your question is not clear at all

Comment: If you can't boot into Windows then you cannot perform the required steps to solve your problem.  outside of accessing your files from another PC you are out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

If W10 isn't starting I'm suspecting the repair has gone south / corrupt and your best recourse is to salvage what you can and plan for a possible wipe/reload.

Like Ramhound suggests you'll have to pull the W10 drive out and slave it on another PC to copy your data to another drive.